Show all subscribed groups, even without new articles, in Gnus by default
I have the following function:
(defun my/gnus-group-list-subscribed-groups ()
  (interactive)
  (gnus-group-list-all-groups gnus-level-subscribed))

The most natural approach would likely be to add this function to gnus-group-prepared-hook, but this hook simply doesn't exist: I tried searching through the Emacs source code but couldn't find any references to it.
Adding it into gnus-group-prepare-hook results in the error put-text-property: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’: 1601.
I would prefer not to add all my subscribed groups to gnus-permanently-visible-groups, since In this case I would have to update this variable every time I subscribe/unsubscribe.

What does "More preferable" mean? The phrase invites opinion-based answers which are frowned upon on Emacs SE. Can you please rephrase the question so that it can be answered using objective criteria?

And also: doesn't Gnus show exactly the subscribed groups when you start up? Why do you have to customize anything in that respect?


And also: doesn't Gnus show exactly the subscribed groups when you start up?

I want to show all subscribed groups, not only containing new articles.
